# Enable Horizontal scroll XAML

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, horizontal-scrolling

I have the following XAML:

```
        <Grid>

            <ListView x:Name="IconTextGrid" Height="500">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="220" Height="60">
                            <Border Background="#66727272" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="10">
                                <Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Height="32" Width="32" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                            </Border>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Text="Ay Lorem Ipsum" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Dolor sit amet" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="8"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
            </ListView>

        </Grid> 
</Page>
```

Which should present items that can be selected by the user.
The problem here is that When I have more than few items (like more than 100) there is no horizontal scroll.
My question is why and how can I fix it?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this...

```
<Grid>
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"> 
     <ListView x:Name="IconTextGrid" Height="500">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="220" Height="60">
                        <Border Background="#66727272" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="10">
                            <Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Height="32" Width="32" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="Ay Lorem Ipsum" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Dolor sit amet" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="8"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>                
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: sorry my mistake place the ScrollViewer within the grid element...
and place the element you want to be scrolled with in the ScrollViewer tag..

Comment: Thanks it works, but it doesn't responding when I try to scroll with the mouse scroller